# Creating an instance of an object with a char[] property

Tags: c#, oop, object

I have a class with an char[] property, but when I try to create an instance of it I get an error. My code is this:

Class:

```
public class Board
{
    private char[] priFC;

    public Board(char[] priFC){
        this.priFC = priFC;
    }
...}
```

Main:

```
Board Tab = new Board(char[10]);
```

I get an invalid expression term char at the creation of Tab

Answer (score 2):

In Main, while creating instance of `Tablero` pass instance of `char[]`, instead of `char[10]`
something like

```
Tablero Tab = new Tablero(new []{'s','t','a','c','k','o','v','e','r','f','l','o','w'});
```

or

```
Tablero Tab = new Tablero(new char[10]);
```

or

```
char [] charInstance = new char[]{'s','t','a','c','k','o','v','e','r','f','l','o','w'};
Tablero Tab = new Tablero(charInstance);
```

Comment: ... or `new char[10]`

Comment: Also the `char` in your first example and `new char[]` in your last one are redundant, you can simply remove them and still works.

Comment: @S.Akbari, I updated my answer. I agree that is redundant but it is not wrong